# Не работает ссылка и иконка в кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Делаю кнопку для таплинка. Сама кнопка уже есть, возникли проблемы с интеграцией ее в сам таплинк. Сама кнопка показывается, но не показывается иконка fontawesome и не работает ссылка при нажатии на кнопку. С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

---

Ссылка на код: https://pastebin.com/UcRvvVMJ

Comment: Выложите код сниппетом на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представленный вами код работает, при его запуске иконка fontawesome отображается и ссылка работает. Вот - [клик](https://codepen.io/kah3vich/pen/MWopapj) 
Ваш код :

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec705a4d25.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<div class="wrapper-button">
      <div class="icon-button whatsapp">
        <div class="tooltip">WhatsApp</div>
        <span>
          <a href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <style type="text/css">
      .wrapper-button {
        display: inline-flex;
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .icon-button {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #AE978F;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 5px 8px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .tooltip::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 8px;
        width: 8px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        bottom: -3px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .icon-button:hover .tooltip {
        top: -45px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        pointer-events: auto;
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .icon-button:hover span,
      .wrapper-button .icon-button:hover .tooltip {
        text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
 
      .wrapper-button .whatsapp:hover,
      .wrapper-button .whatsapp:hover .tooltip,
      .wrapper-button .whatsapp:hover .tooltip::before {
        background-color: #43d854;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
    </style>
```

[image: пример работы кнопки]